How to give username with space during SignUp in Manage Auth0
Im getting below errror
Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the following characters: '_', '+', '-', '.', '!', '#', '$', ''', '^', '`', '~' and '@'

Here is the screenshot of error when i try to sigup using username with space i given
enter image description here
Why this error is coming during sign-up page specially i want to add space between names like first name space should have then last name
how i can solve it
